# How to properly parse a data string with awk

Tags: bash, awk

so I'm trying to parse this data string:
pyof.v0x04.common.action.ActionSetField object at 0x7ff55bd06b38

And I'm trying to use awk because its always been very helpful, but for some reason I'm not able to parse at all the part of the string I need which is "ActionSetField".

This is what I've tried so far with no result:

`sh-3.2# echo -e "pyof.v0x04.common.action.ActionSetField object at 0x7ff55bd06b38" | awk -F '.' '{print $5}'`

ActionSetField object at 0x7ff55bd06b38

`sh-3.2# echo -e "pyof.v0x04.common.action.ActionSetField object at 0x7ff55bd06b38" | awk -F '.' '{print $5}' | awk '{print $0}'`

ActionSetField object at 0x7ff55bd06b38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$1` in your second `awk` or...

```
$ echo "pyof.v0x04.common.action.ActionSetField object at 0x7ff55bd06b38" | 
  awk '{print f[split($1,f,".")]}'            

ActionSetField
```

Answer (score 1):

> echo "pyof.v0x04.common.action.ActionSetField object at 0x7ff55bd06b38" | awk -F '.' '{print $5}'
> ActionSetField object at 0x7ff55bd06b38

I'm not sure why that does what it does.  The **-F** option takes a regular expression, and `.` matches any character but a newline.  Evidently, awk treats `.` as a literal, and you get everything after the 4th `.` because there's no further separator.

Still, we have options.  All we have to do is refine the splitting:

```
$ echo "pyof.v0x04.common.action.ActionSetField object at 0x7ff55bd06b38" | 
  awk  '{split($1, a, /[.]/); print a[5]}'
ActionSetField
```

or

```
$ echo "pyof.v0x04.common.action.ActionSetField object at 0x7ff55bd06b38" |
  awk -F '[. ]' '{print $5}'
ActionSetField
```

In the first case, awk splits on whitespace, and we use the split command to produce an array from the first field, and print the last element.

In the second case, we set the field separator to `[. ]`, either a `.` or a space. awk then splits the line into 8 fields, and we print the 5th one.